# How does SKScene.anchorPoint affects physicsBody?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

When I changed anchorPoint for the GameScene `(from default 0,0 to 0.5,0.5)` the physicsBody for the sprite `disappeared` from the screen `debugging with kView.showsPhysics = true`.

It still exists, because each ship collides with each other but it looks like position of the physicsBody was shifted (out of screen).

Why this change affects physicsBody of scene's child?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(0, 0)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

            sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 100)

            sprite.xScale = 0.5
            sprite.yScale = 0.5
            sprite.position = location

            let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

            sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

            self.addChild(sprite)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's weird, I just found that in iOS 8.0 simulator it works (physicsBody is unaffected), but in 7.1 physicsBody is shifted to the bottom left corner of the SKScene

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in old SDK because it's same on 10.9 and it's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing. I put the anchor point of the SKScene also in the middle (CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)) and it totally destroyed the physics. You will notice this especially when adding joints to the physics scene, you will not be able to put the physics joint anchor points in the right place.

My advice, don't change the SKScene anchorpoint if using SKPhysics (costs me a lot of time and rewriting to find out).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the anchor point of the scene does not change coordinate of physics world. The same goes with every node and its physics body. With your own nodes you can compensate using special SKPhysicsBody init with center: (the center in the owning node’s coordinate system).

With physics world as for now you can do nothing.